# How can i execute several scenarios simultaneously without using several thread groups

Tags: jmeter

I have created seven thread groups which execute different scenarios in one application. I'm trying to optimize my scripts in order to be more maintainable and easy to master when someone else uses them.

The thing that i cannot figure out is how can i combine those thread groups into one or two and to still have the seven different execution paths and the possibility to control them, by control i mean to set how many users to execute scenario 1, how many to execute scenario 2 etc. till 7.

Currently the test plan looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want several thread groups for some reason the alternative options are in:

- [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) - with different global executions or execution percentages
- [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) - which provides random weighted values (in some cases Throughput Controller doesn't guarantee that samplers in scope will ever be executed)

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide for more information on configuration and implementation.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri your solution was even better !

Answer (score 0):

Well i just figured out how to do that i have added a Loop controller a Random Order Controller as child of the loop controller. And i have put seven throughput controllers as child of the Random Order Controller so now everything looks fine [image]